# Performance of HTTP POSTS from Firemonkey Android app has suddenly collapsed when on mobile data

Tags: android, http, delphi, mobile, firemonkey

A Delphi 10.2.3 Firemonkey app on Android

I've had this app running and in use for about 6 months, and it's been fine. I recompiled the code after Windows Spring Update (I don't know if this is related), and the performance of HTTP POSTS has dramatically slowed e.g. a 49 byte response (to a simple request) is taking over 10 seconds whereas on wifi it's about 0.1 seconds.

It's not the server side, in the sense that the connection is very brief, as one would expect.

To do the connection, I'm using idHTTP, which has always worked fine.

No code changed, I've tried a number of different networks, good signal and bad (it makes no real difference). Checked all the usual things, connections closing, things are freed as they should be, etc.

Any ideas? Is there some parameter I should look at?

(Edit)
* Just to add, any test app that only does this sort of connection has the same problem. 0.1 seconds on wifi, 16 seconds in mobile data.
* I realised I hadn't checked a GET - they work fine, nice 0.1 sec response to the same request, but run as a get.

So it looks like there's something weird about the POST.

(Edit)
Completed a fresh Windows & Delphi install, and tested using a small android app that with 2 buttons, Get & Post, calling web services that simply return the parameters. No change. POST takes 10-ish seconds, GET takes about 0.1.

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: What does the Windows Spring Update have to do with Android? Is your HTTP client actually running on Windows, or is it running on Android?

Comment: It coincided, that's all. I can't see how it could have an effect. It slow on Windows and Android.

Comment: try with HttpClient instead of indy to see if it's change something

Comment: First of all this question lacks proper [mcve]. Then it lacks other relevant information. If this is Android app, then Windows version under which it is compiled is not relevant, but the compiler version (exact Delphi version) and the frameworks you used are relevant. Since, you could not had 10.2.3 application running for 6 months, obviously your "properly working" application was compiled with different Delphi version.